# Updating post in frontend: send post ID to functions.php

Tags: wordpress

This is a very simple form I'm suing to update posts in frontend:

```
<?php $current_post = $post->ID; ?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
    <textarea name="text"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="edit post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'edit_post', 'edit_post_nonce' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_post" value="true" />
</form>
```

In functions.php, I have the following script (I remove the verifications lines):

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['edit_post'] )) {
    global $current_post;

    $post = array(
        'ID' => $current_post,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']),
        'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['text']),
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );

    $post_id = wp_update_post( $post );

    if ( $post_id ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('list-posts/?status=edit') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

But instead edit the post, WP create a new one. This is because `$current_post` value are not sent to functions.php. How can I do that without using input to store post ID?

**UPDATE**

Problem fixed:

```
function edit_post_foo($query){
   $id = get_the_id();

   $post = array(
        'ID' => $id,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']),
        'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['text']),
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );

    $post_id = wp_update_post( $post );

    if ( $post_id ) {
        wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
        exit;
    }
}

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['edit_post'] )) {

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['edit_post_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['edit_post_nonce'], 'edit_post' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST['title']))){
        $erro = "inform a title.";
        return;
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST['text']))){
        $erro = "sen a text.";
        return;
    }

    add_action("wp", "edit_post_foo");
}
```

Comment: @rnevius I'm thinking using wp hooks where I can grab post id

Comment: Headers will likely have already been sent if you try waiting for the query to run / post object to be created...

Comment: @rnevius Humm. So the better solution is to add post add as a hidden input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe find a solution.

First, in your form add an input type with name="action" and value="your_custom_function"

Then

Create your function in your functions.php

```
function your_function($query)
{
   $id = get_the_id();

   // do something

   wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
   exit;
}
if( isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "your_custom_value" )
  add_action("wp", "your_function");
```

At this moment, you can get the current id of the current post.
Then update your post.
The id stay hidden for the user.

It's only work if your send the form on the page of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest u a tutoriel that explain how to create a new post from frontend.

[@here](http://nozifel.fr/tutoriels/creer-un-formulaire-cote-front-avec-creation-dun-post/)

Just add an hidden action in your form, then create a function with the value of the hidden input.

Don't forget to pass the post_id in the post array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I'm looking for a solution where post id cannot be changed by user.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following and it should work:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
    <textarea name="text"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="edit post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'edit_post', 'edit_post_nonce' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_post" value="true" />
</form>

<?php
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['edit_post'] )) {
        $current_post = $_POST['postID'];

        $post = array(
            'ID' => $current_post,
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']),
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['text']),
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        );

        $post_id = wp_update_post( $post );

        if ( $post_id ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('list-posts/?status=edit') );
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

If this is for a front-end editor, you may want to consider using [wp-editor()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) instead of a textarea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I would like separate views from functions. So I'm trying to put submit function in functions.php file. And a way to submit post id where user cannot change it.

Comment: Would you be ok with using Ajax instead of a submit?